# Notifications not working in Gnome 3.4

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Notifications are no longer working in Gnome 3.4 but they are working in Unity.  I have tried everything I can think of but I am stumped.

To clarify, I am changing the theme using Gnome Tweak. Themes were obtained from various repositories including noobslab/themes and webupd8. As an example, when using the default theme adwaita, I get all notifications when using Rhythmbox as to what song is being played on an internet radio station. I even tried a different media player with the same result. When I change the theme, all I get is a media player Icon.  Change back to default theme and all Notifications work fine.  Notifications were working at first with all themes, but no longer. The question is how to get Notifications to work for all themes. They did for previous versions of Gnome-shell.

Comment: Have you definitively used a gnome3.4 compatible theme?  I presume you are aware that gnome3.2 themes will give you display issues when used on gnome 3.4?

Comment: Yes, all themes currently installed are 3.4 compatible.

Comment: ok - it would be very useful if you can provide the exact links and themes you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, for the delay.  I removed all themes.  I then installed the webupd8team/themes/ubuntu theme.  Rebooted and still get the same issue except for the default theme.

Comment: I am more convinced that this is an update that messed things up or a simple fix we are not aware of.  I found another user in the ubuntuforums with the same issue.

Comment: what is the list of gnome-shell extensions you have installed (perhaps try a new user but dont switch on any extensions).  You wouldnt per-chance have this gnome-shell extension installed? https://github.com/hackedbellini/Gnome-Shell-Notifications-Alert

Comment: I should have mentioned that I logged into the Guest Account as soon as this problem began.  I have the weather extension, Native Window Placement, Media Player Indicator, Places Status Indicator, Dock Extension, Applications Menu, window navigator, Gajim IM, and that's it. Don't have the above extension installed.  Turning all extensions off and rebooting does not fix the problem. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Here is the other post I found regarding this issue:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11911639#post11911639

Comment: Could it be a problem of the font color, i.e. black font on black background?

Comment: I assume you mean with the Wallpaper.  The wallpaper is blue so I don't think that's it.

Comment: I have a feeling this bounty will expire without a resolution.  I've tried everything I could think of that has been suggested before it was suggested.  I do appreciate the effort. :(

Answer (score 2):

I've found how fix this:

It's in the `gnome-shell.css` file from the theme package. Some id definitions need the class name definition:

Example:

```
#notification {
```

Change to this:

```
#notification, .notification {
```

and some other definition... to sumup you have to compare with the `gnome-shell.css` file in /`usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`.

Comment: I'll have to take your word for it.  Last week, updates hosed my system for no apparent reason.  I dropped Mint for this very issue earlier this year.  I re-installed 12.04 and it seems to be running fine (Unity and Gnome 3.4).  Thanks for the info in case it should happen again