# Gnome shell notifications without text

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notifications not working in Gnome 3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132229/notifications-not-working-in-gnome-3-4)

I've just changed the theme of my gnome shell. Sine then the notifications appears with out text ..

I can click in the icon but no text is shown

How Can I solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue. I offered a bounty but no solutions

Comment: What was your old theme, and what's your new theme? Does changing the theme back fix the problem? (I'm not saying you should accept that as a solution, but this is useful information for troubleshooting.)

Answer (score 0):

Try another theme. Make sure in the description of the theme page has "3.4 compatible" in it.